# Webpage displays incorrectly on different resolutions due to incorrect css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues with a webpage of mine, mainly on mobile devices but it also affects desktop devices too, **I would be willing to award a bounty (as and when stackoverflow allows me) to whomever can help with these problems**

#### HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bbFsMcwT

#### CSS: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SGMwt3cs

#### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D8SJD/

- **Issue 1 - Left/Right Scroll Image Buttons**

  - Currently my left and right scroll image buttons are done in html using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` I want to be able to convert them into css based "buttons"

---

- **Issue 2 - Dynamic Resolution(s)**

  - The header and footers aren't dynamic with different resolutions for example, I created the page designed on a 1680x1050 monitor which looks like: [Desktop 1680x1050](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vCYr.png) however making the window smaller it looks like: [Desktop Small Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzjR2.png)
  - On a Nexus 4 mobile phone on default zoom it looks like: [Mobile Original Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMBZ3.png)
  - On a Nexus 4 mobile phone zoomed out to as far as it can go it looks like: [Mobile Max Distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UsIG.png)
  - On a Nexus 4 zoomed out and scrolled to the bottom (so that the browsers URL bar disappears) it looks like: [Zoomed out without URL bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1RIa.png) **(the footer of the actual webpage vanishes)**
  - On a Nexus 4 zoomed out and scrolled just off from the bottom (so that the browsers URL bar is visible) it looks like: [Zoomed out with URL bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrCzH.png) **(the footer returns)**
    .
- The placeholder image and arrows are supposed to be in the center of the footer and headers and should shrink in accordance to the screen resolution.
- Mobile device default zoom (if possible) needs to be decreased so they can see more and on getting smaller (if possible) if it gets close to [Mobile Original Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMBZ3.png) then the `Up to Top`, `Down to Key`, ***placeholder logos*** should vanish...
- **Please see images at bottom of this post**

For the mobile devices I tried things like below just for testing but none of them worked...

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    #header > a img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

#### EDIT 14/11/2013 @ 01:58GMT

On a 1920x1080 screen it looks kind of okay although there is a big gap between the text and the placeholder image as seen below:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/vWoEpK8.png]

On a 1680x1050 screen it looks roughly how it should take note of where "Semi" is located and compare to the 1920x1080 image from above.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/SEppf7n.png]

On a 600x600 screen it appears as follows, which as you can see there is a big gap between the placeholder and the left arrow but on the right arrow there is no gap and infact it overflows, as for the text it too is too far to the right.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/QcRhW3B.png]

Comment: If you're going to downvote this post at least give a constructive reason as to why you feel it needs a downvote.

Comment: This question would probably be more answerable if you could narrow down the code to *only* the relevant HTML and CSS, rather than providing a huge block of code and making users scan through it all to figure out the relevant parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I've tried to filter out all of the irrelevant code for this solution.

See the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8SJD/6/).

Most of the time, it is best to use relative positioning to fit elements absolutely inside of another element. In your case, with three different strings to fit in a 300x80 window, it's a bit crowded. I tried to place things in a logical position to demonstrate.

By placing a container in the `footimage` div with relative position, you can then place every element inside the `footimage` div absolutely relavtive to the `footimage` div, rather than to the entire page.

For example, what you had:

```
#footer .footmid
{

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Will place the div of class `footmid` at a position 50% of the page height from the top of the page and 50% of the page width from the left of the page:

[image]

This will work if every user that visits your page has the exact same resolution, however it causes problems when the don't. Obviously, this isn't a perfect world, so different resolutions will visit your page.

What you can do is use relative positioning!

Basically I tell CSS that instead of moving 50% from the top and left of the window, move 50% from the top and left of the nearest parent element with relative positioning:

[image]

You can modify the `bottom`, `left`, and `right` attributes of [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8SJD/6/) to move the `footmid` elements within the relative element `.footimageContainer` that is the same size and in the same position as the `.footimage`.

---

As far as your arrows, I wasn't quite sure what you were trying to accomplish; your question was pretty vague, so I simply made them fade out slightly when you mouseover them. Any mouseover/out events can be handled using CSS psuedo-elements.

```
.element //Native and mouseout
{} 

.element:hover //onmouseover
{}
```

Remember that if you use pseudo-elements, you have to specify the attribute that will be changing in both the native and :hover rules.

```
.element
{color:red;}

.element
{color:black;}
```

If you have any additional questions on the arrows, let me know and I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Type

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  /* Your specific styles go here */
}
```

and dont forget to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Would you be able to create a jsfiddle for that? I'm unsure how to get your @mediascreen working :S

Comment: [@media](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) is the basis of today's responsive design - it allows you to specify CSS based on the width of the screen, and is dynamic. You should definitely look at it further, as I think it's the fix you're seeking

Comment: I've edited this answer so you can just paste in the @media stuff to the end of your style block/document. Any styles you place in there will override the global style as long as the wrapping rules are satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

I see a border around your links, remove from your links:

```
a{
    border:none ;
}
```

for first issue you can do it with CSS, just remove `<img>` tag inside `<a>` tag like this:

```
<div class="footleft">
   <a class="def" href="javascript: void(0);">

   </a>
</div>
```

create image buttons like this:

[image]
[image]

then set background to `<a>` tag like this:

```
#footer .footleft a {
width: 100px;
height: 47px;
display: block;
background: url(path/to/leftarrow.png);
background-position: 0 0;
}

#footer .footright a{
width: 100px;
height: 47px;
display: block;
background: url(path/to/rightarrow.png);
background-position: 0 0;
}

#footer .footleft a:hover , #footer .footright a:hover{
background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

second issue, I think if you remove `position:absolute;` from `#header .headimage` and `#footer .footimage` it will be okay.

and if your want to centerize `headmid` and `footmid` and `footmidtwo` you have two choices,

First: set fixed width to them and use CSS like this:

```
#footer .footmid {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 15px;
width: 292px;
margin-left: -146px;
}

#footer .footmidtwo {
top: 70%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 15px;
width: 126px;
margin-left: -63px;
}

#header .headmid {
top: 60%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 15px;
width: 302px;
margin-left: -151px;
}
```

Second: if you need to have dynamic width you can use this CSS and JQuery:

CSS:

```
#header .headmid {
top: 60%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 15px;
}

#footer .footmid {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 15px;
}

#footer .footmidtwo {
top: 70%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var $widthhead = $(".headmid").width();
var $widthfoot = $(".footmid").width();
var $widthfoot2 = $(".footmidtwo").width();

$(".headmid").css("margin-left",$widthhead/2*(-1));
$(".footmid").css("margin-left",$widthfoot/2*(-1));
$(".footmidtwo").css("margin-left",$widthfoot2/2*(-1));
```

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/D8SJD/1/)

Comment: Some of your changes look good I've taken most into account, I've disposed of footmid and footmidtwo however I still use headmid. I'm wanting the headmid to be offset so that it appears like: http://i.imgur.com/VJPJHyX.png in comparison toe the placeholder at the top, where as your jsfiddle puts it exactly in the middle. I'd also like to offset the bottom image by -10 or so pixels so that it overhangs onto the table. The only other issue I have after that is the fact on mobile devices the header image doesn't disappear correctly/appear correctly when using the suggestion from Carlos.

Comment: On small devices when the placeholder can no longer fit in the page correctly (overhangs onto arrows) I'd like to replace the bottom image with some simple text but place it right at the bottom and when the top image overhangs onto the Prevous Class text it should remove itself or keep adjusting towards the right until it can no longer fit and then remove itself and just re-adjust the Up to Top | Down to Bottom to the top right of the screen...

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/D8SJD/4/

Instead of using absolute positioning, you can just take advantage of the text-align center and images and text will center automatically.

If you want offset from center, try position:relative, and top, left, right etc and it will move relative to it's central position.

Elements that are display:inline; or display:inline-block; will align according to parents text-align property, in this case text-align:center.

```
#footer .footimage {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
}

#footer .footmid {
    top: 50%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#footer .footmidtwo {
    top: 70%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per issue 2, i could be wrong but when targeting the image through the structure of the site 
i.e.

```
headImg a img{...}
```

The style wouldn't work. But if you add classes to the images the style will work; the case could be that there are some unclosed divs or elements messing with the architecture.

```
<div class="headimage">
    <a href="url" target="_blank"><img class="placeholder" src="http://placehold.it/300x80"/></a>
</div>

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .placeholder {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

JsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Q5bEb/

Comment: Interesting that works pretty nicely, I do however have other issues with the placeholder and the other images/text in the headers and footers, I've added some images and information in the original post.